# Unable to connect to MSSQL from Python

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, pyodbc, freetds

my Python code:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;DSN=S29;UID=test;PWD=test;TDS_Version=8.0;ClientCharset=UTF8')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select user_id, user_name from users")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
  print row.user_id, row.user_name
```

Get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../test_mssql_connect.py", line 4, in <module>
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;DSN=S29;UID=test;PWD=test;TDS_Version=8.0;ClientCharset=UTF8')
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[]  (20013) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I can not find the information, what is this error **('HY000', '[]  (20013) (SQLDriverConnect)')** and how to fix it.

At the same time through **tsql**, **osql** and **isql** I successfully connected to the base

my **odbc.ini**

```
[S29]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=S29
ServerName=192.168.0.29
Database=test
UID=test
PWD=test
TDS_Version=8.0
```

my **odbcinst.ini**

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS
Driver=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.1/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.1/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=2
CPTimeout =
CPReuse =
TDS Version = 8.0
client charset = utf-8
```

my **freetds.conf**

```
[global]
tds version = 8.0
[192.168.0.29]
host = 192.168.0.29
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
[S29]
host = 192.168.0.29
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

Comment: Can you telnet to the SQL Server IP address from the machine you're running the code on? From a terminal (cmd on Windows), try: `telnet 192.168.0.29 1433` If it connects, you're good. If it just says at 'Connecting...' you can't reach the remote SQL Server.

Comment: Connect via telnet is successful, moreover all the tests from the console using **tsql, osql** and **isql** also going well, but the connection is not working from python.
On the server CentOS connection from python all works, but on my work Mac is not working in any way.

Answer (score 0):

What is your freetds.conf set up? Note, you'll most likely want to use TDS Version 7.3, though I don't think that's the problem, though it may be, since it defaults to TDS Version 7.1. Documentation here for TDS Version numbers supported by FreeTDS:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

You may have to provide the port number, but without seeing your freetds.conf DSN set up, it is hard to tell. I've had better luck without DSNs from Python. Since 8.0 isn't a valid TDS version, I'll provide you with a full example that works for me:

freetds.conf:

```
[examplesql]
        host = examplesql.server.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.3
```

odbc.ini:

```
[examplesql]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = examplesql.server.com
Port = 1433
TDS_Version = 7.3
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS with Protocol up to 7.3
Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
```

pyodbc connect, DSN free:

```
DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=examplesql.server.com;PORT=1433;DATABASE=dbname;UID=dbuser;PWD=dbpassword;TDS_Version=7.3;
```

**You'll have to modify the odbcinst.ini to point to where your driver lives.** A few notes:

- You'll have to update the TDS version to match the version of SQL Server you are running and the Free TDS version you are running. Version 0.95 supports TDS Version 7.3.
- TDS Version 7.3 will work with MS SQL Server 2008 and above.
- Use TDS Version 7.2 for MS SQL Server 2005.

See here for more:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd339982.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: Switching versions Free TDS in ini files does not give any results. The problem is not exactly in this place. Therefore, in my tests, I used a version 8.0

Comment: Here's an odd problem I ran into: is your username or password longer than 25 characters? FreeTDS limits the fields to 25 characters, IIRC. Can you include the full error you're getting as well, or is that the entire snippet above?

Comment: Password is the same as in the example. The error is shown in full, here is a [screenshot](http://joxi.ru/52a1PqouRayX20) of the console

Comment: In that case, I'm at a loss. Sorry! Perhaps try connecting using the SERVER= example?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall **pyodbc**, now works.
I download it here https://github.com/juztin/pyodbc

```
 python setup.py build install --macports
```